# how to improve LBP operator by reducing feature dimension

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction, lbph-algorithm

I am using [LBP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) with MATLAB for extraction feature but the accuracy is too low

how to reduce the feature bins in LBP?

many thanks.

Comment: why do think it is a problem with too high dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`pcares`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pcares.html) function to do that.  `pcares` stands for **PCA Residuals**:

```
[residuals, reconstructed] = pcares(X, ndim);
```

`residuals` returns the residuals obtained by retaining `ndim` principal components of the `n-by-p` matrix `X`. `X` is the **data** matrix, or the matrix that contains your data.  Rows of `X` correspond to observations and columns are the variables. `ndim` is a scalar and must be less than or equal to `p`. `residuals` is a matrix of the same size as `X`.

`reconstructed` will have the reduced dimensional data based on the `ndim` input.  Note that `reconstructed` will still be in the original dimension as `X`.  As such, you can choose the first `ndim` columns and this will correspond to those features constructed using the number of the dimensions for the feature specified by `ndim`.  In other words:

```
reduced = reconstructed(:,1:ndim);
```

As such, `reduced` will contain your data that was dimension reduced down to `ndim` dimensions.

## Small Note

You need the Statistics Toolbox in order to run `pcares`.  If you don't, then this method won't work.

Comment: can you help me, I have 480(rows)*256(columns) which extracted by LBP operator.so i need to get the similarity matrices to apply the verification scenario. e.g vector one with itself will give zero and vector one with vector two will give score and so on